# loop through all the text-boxes of a table and check the mandatory values

Tags: jquery

I have a table of 3 columns and 10 rows which contains text fields. If I add any values into any of the cell, the corresponding row's first column field is mandatory and if there is no text it will throw an error message like "please add value in column 1" and the program will be paused to correct the input. How can I achieve this using jQuery?

My sample code:

```
$(function() {$("#mySubmit").click(function(event) {

$('#myTable tr').each(function(event) {
    if ($(this).find("td:first").length > 0) {
        var firstColumn     = $(this).find("td input").eq(0).val(); 
        var secondColumn = $(this).find("td input").eq(1).val();
        if (typeof (secondColumn) != "undefined") {
                var lengthOfSecondColumn = secondColumn.length;
                var lengthOfFirstColumn = firstColumn.length;

                alert(lengthOfFirstColumn + ' ' + lengthOfSecondColumn )

                if (lengthOfSecondColumn > 0) {

                    if(lengthOfFirstColumn < 1){
                        alert('Please add value in first column');
                        event.preventDefault();
                    }               
                }
        }                                       
    }
});

    $.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url : "updateURL",
    data : dataString,
    success : function(data) {
        if (data.checkingStatus == 0) {
            alert("updated");
        }

        else (data.checkingStatus == -1) {
            alert("...");
        }
    }
    });

});
```

I tried to do this. But it is executed and redirects to custom error handling page.

Comment: This is a Q&A platform. It doesn't work like this. You have to try, tell us what you tried, what didn't work, and we'll tell you where it went wrong and what you should do about it. We don't code for you. I'm sorry.

Comment: I dont ask for the code. I just ask the basic to do so. Sorry, I may not ask the question properly.

Comment: when is this piece of code supposed to be executed?

Comment: There is a submit button and when the button will be clicked, then the code will be executed.

Comment: So I'm guessing this piece of code is inside a submit handler, right ? You should use preventDefault on that event then, instead of calling each with another event.

Comment: Yes, the code is inside a submit handler.

Comment: Then remove that 'event' parameter for the each function, so that the preventDefault is called on the first submit event.

Comment: Do you mean, ... each(function() { ... } in this way? I tried that but it redirects to the custom error page

Comment: Is your submit handler called with an `event` parameter as well ? PLease include it in your code.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48286/discussion-between-user3150012-and-romain-braun)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
$(function() {$("#mySubmit").click(function(event) {
var valid = true; // Add a variable

$('#myTable tr').each(function() { // remove 'event'
    if ($(this).find("td:first").length > 0) {
        var firstColumn     = $(this).find("td input").eq(0).val(); 
        var secondColumn = $(this).find("td input").eq(1).val();
        if (typeof (secondColumn) != "undefined") {
                var lengthOfSecondColumn = secondColumn.length;
                var lengthOfFirstColumn = firstColumn.length;

                alert(lengthOfFirstColumn + ' ' + lengthOfSecondColumn )

                if (lengthOfSecondColumn > 0) {

                    if(lengthOfFirstColumn < 1){
                        alert('Please add value in first column');
                        event.preventDefault();
                        valid = false; //set variable to false if there was a problem
                        return false; //exit the loop;
                    }               
                }
        }                                       
    }
});
    if(valid) { //Only if form is valid
        $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : "updateURL",
        data : dataString,
        success : function(data) {
            if (data.checkingStatus == 0) {
                alert("updated");
            }

            else (data.checkingStatus == -1) {
                alert("...");
            }
        }
        });
    }
});
```